# Technical term for summation of sequential numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Given $n$, I wish to do the following operation: $f(n) = n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1$. For example, $f(4) = 10$. What is the technical term for this kind of operation?

Comment: A sum? $f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i$

Comment: $$f(n)=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: The number $f(n)$ is called the $n$th *triangular number*.

Comment: The operation is called *summing*. You are summing the sequence $a_k = k$ from $k=1$ to $k=n$.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, however I'm looking for terminology. If I wanted to say what this was in one word, what would it be? e.g. for $g(n) = n \times (n-1) \times (n-2) ... \times 1$, I can simply say I'm finding the *factorial* of $n$

Comment: If $f(n)$ as shown by @Nilan is not divided by $2,$ then it is the $n$th pronic number.

Comment: A pronic number, by definition from Wikipedia, is a product of two consecutive numbers. I'm looking for the term for the **sum** of two or more consecutive numbers.

Comment: The function $$f(n) = \sum_{k = 1}^n k$$ is the $n$th partial sum of the arithmetic series with initial term $1$ and common difference $1$.  This particular example is known as the $n$th triangular number.

Comment: Thank you and also @zarathustra, the *n*th triangular number seems to be the best term to describe my function.